# Keeping bar colors same until another condition occurs in pinescript

Tags: pine-script

I have two different conditions that colors bars accordingly. If these two conditions aren't met, bar colors stay as default colors (or na). I am having a chart with bars as blue, blue, na, blue, na, yellow, na, yellow etc.

What I would like to do is to paint all bars with same color until second condition happens. Meaning that all bars will be blue until yellow bar appears and all bars will be yellow after blue bar appears.

As in below image, I want all gray bars between and around blue bars until first yellow bar appears, and vice versa

[barcolors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCTSV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Cem,

I am new too. Its hard to assist without showing some code, maybe provide a section of the code.

But would you not just change the na to gray. Obs Up and Down would be defined.

```
barcolor(Up ? color.blue : Down ? color.yellow : color.gray, transp=70)
```

Try the below

```
UpCond = fastEMA[1]>slowEMA[1] and high>high[1]
DownCond = fastEMA[1]<slowEMA[1] and hist[1] < 0 and low<low[1]

barcolor(UpCond ? color.blue : DownCond ? color.yellow : color.gray, transp=70)
```

Comment: barcolor(fastEMA[1]>slowEMA[1] and hist[1] > 0 and high>high[1] ? yellow : na)

barcolor(fastEMA[1]<slowEMA[1] and hist[1] < 0 and low<low[1] ? blue : na)

barcolor(gray)

this is the piece of code that put colors. It checks crossing ema's and paint next bar meeting condition

Comment: UpCond = fastEMA[1]>slowEMA[1] and high>high[1]


DownCond = fastEMA[1]<slowEMA[1] and hist[1] < 0 and low<low[1]



barcolor(UpCond ? color.blue : DownCond ? color.yellow : color.gray, transp=70)

Comment: I actually need to paint gray bars to blue or yellow